# VB.Net Application starts as background process in Windows 10

Tags: vb.net, windows-10

We have an internally developed VB.Net Windows Forms Application that handles all our Auto-Updating for our other software applications. Whenever I run the application in Windows 10, the application starts under the "Background Processes" section of the Task Manager. The only way I can get it to run in the foreground is to run it as an Administrator even though I'm an Admin on the VM and my UAC settings are turned all the way down. This doesn't happen in Windows 7 or 8 so I'm wondering if there's something I'm doing wrong or something about Windows 10 that's changed where it has to be run as an Admin. Our other applications don't seem to have this issue, it's just specifically this one application for some reason but I can't seem to figure out what's different.

Comment: Umm, I don't think there is a tab for Background processes. Can't see one on my PC when I open task manager.

Comment: Its under the Processes tab, there should be a section labeled "Apps" which are applications running in the foreground and then below that is a section labeled "Background Processes".

Comment: The distinction between background processes and non-background processes is whether the process is displaying any windows. We can't really tell you how to fix it unless you show us the code and configuration settings for this project. Does it show any windows? Does it only show them if the user is an admin?

Comment: @user3097176 Ahhhhh - when "Group by type" is selected in the view menu - got it. Thanks

Comment: It does show a window and it works fine when I run in on a Windows 7 or 8 VM but for some reason it doesn't work with Windows 10. Even as an Admin on the VM if I double-click the EXE to run it (it's usually called by another application) it still starts in the background processes.

The application is a standard Windows Form but it also has a class built into it that handles WCF communication calls to update it (it basically shows the current status of the Auto Update).

Answer (score 1):

So I put some more error handling in and it sounds like @xfx was onto the right idea. The application is erring when it starts up because it can't register the URL of the WCF service so it never got to the point where it was displaying the form. Once I manually registered the URL of the WCF service and ran the application as an Admin, it displayed and worked like normal.

Answer (score 0):

This is because of the way the project has been configured in Visual Studio.
Here's how to create an application that behaves like a background process:

- In the Project settings dialog, disable the `Enable application framework` option
- Next, change the `Startup object` to `Sub Main`
- Finally, add a Module to the project and add the following code:

  ```
  Module Module1
      Sub Main()
          Application.Run()
      End Sub
  End Module
  ```

If you run the application (not from within the IDE, but directly) it will behave just like the one you describe.

The application will remain as a background process as long as it doesn't display a `Form`. As soon as one is displayed, you will see that Task Manager moves the process from the Background processes list to the Apps list.

To test this, just change the code in the Module for this version:

```
Imports System.Threading

Module Module1
    Sub Main()
        Dim tmp As New Thread(Sub()
                Thread.Sleep(3000)
                Using f As New Form1()
                    f.ShowDialog()
                End Using
            End Sub)
        tmp.Start()

        Application.Run()
    End Sub
End Module
```

The application will start as a background process and 3 seconds later will display form, becoming a foreground process.

Comment: Looks like you were right, it wasn't getting to the point where it was displaying the form due to errors occurring in the background so once I solved those, it displayed correctly! Thanks!